# ios plugin template (Smartface)

Tags: ios, plugins, smartface.io

Where do you add the CLI command to create an iOS plugin template in ios.

I checked on the Developing iOS Plugin Guide however it doesn't specifically say where the command should be run in.

Answer (score 0):

You should install CLI tool and run CLI command in this tool.

That guide will help you to install tool : https://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/project/clitool/